# ReportLab - Why space has border

Tags: python, reportlab

I write Paragraph like below

```
Paragraph("<para alignment='center'><img src='image location' width='28' height='28' valign='-4'/>&nbsp<font color='blue' size=28>649</font></para>")
```

and got below, space has black border, so how to remove this border?

[image]

Comment: inspect that element?

Comment: why don't you put the space inside the <font> tag?